A man tries to convince a comic book seller that he is a superhero
I'm looking for a live action movie I've seen on German TV (most likely one of the public channels). If I remember correctly, it should have been between 2003 and 2010 that I saw it. Sorry that I can't give a more precise date. I've definitely seen it in German language, but I don't know whether that is the language it was originally filmed in.
The story is that a comic book seller gets visited in the store by a man who tries to convince him that he (the book seller) is a superhero and has to fight a series of crimes that happen in the town (if I recall correctly, a series of murders of women).
In the end,

 the comic book seller discovers that this man is actually the one doing those crimes. However the man himself seems not to have been aware of it, and then concludes that he is the supervillain, because where there is a superhero, there is also a supervillain.

I've tried to search for that movie on the internet and on IMDb, but without success.
Edit: I completely forgot to mention: While the comic book seller indeed solves the crime series, at no point in the film does he show obvious superpowers, as far as I remember.

It really sounds like unbreakable except the roles are inverted. edit : I saw the answer and your comment.

Sounds like Unbreakable,

In Unbreakable, a security guard named David Dunn survives a horrific train crash. After the incident, with the help of a manipulative disabled comic book shop owner named Elijah Price, he learns that he possesses superhuman powers. As Dunn explores and reluctantly confronts his powers while trying to navigate a difficult family life, he begins to fight crime and learns the true nature of Elijah Price.

Trailer :




Thank you, but that was not the movie. First, in Unbreakable, from the excerpt you quoted, the roles are exactly reverse from the movie I saw: As I wrote, the comic book seller was the alleged superhero. BTW, I notice that I had forgotten to write an important point in my question, which I'll edit in, and which from the description should also rule out this movie. I also don't remember a train crash, although I can't completely exclude that I might have missed the beginning part of the movie.

Are you sure of that ? Maybe check the trailer to confirm that. If you watched it 7 years ago, that's pretty common to mix some details.

@M.Polo: I hadn't (for some reason the trailer on IMDb wouldn't play for me), but now I found the trailer on YouTube, and it indeed doesn't look like it's for the movie I've seen. The atmosphere is completely different to the one I remember (I'm not sure if that's the right English term, but if not, I hope you understand anyway what I mean).

OK. Then I'm curious of the title of this movie too.

@celtschk: "The atmosphere is completely different to the one I remember" I saw the trailer for the movie, and when seeing it in cinema, I remember feeling the same way as you. The trailer made it seem more action packed than it really is. The movie is more of a philosophical journey than anything else.

Super?  A clerk at a comic book store becomes the lead character's sidekick.

I now found that someone has uploaded the German version on YouTube (terrible image quality, but sufficient for identification). And I dismissed it too early; now I'm certain that it was indeed this movie. And @Flater is right: The trailer is very misleading.

@celtschk I remember distinctly that the promotion of this film didn't mention that it had anything to do with comic books. (Some friends and I went to see it, and were pleasantly surprised when we found out.) This was following the huge success of The Sixth Sense, so the tone of the Unbreakable trailer was probably trying to match the tone of The Sixth Sense as much as possible.
